# Does Firestore read all documents on page load even if they havent changed?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a chrome extension for the new tab page and I am trying to find the right DB for the project. The only question that is keeping me from using Firebase Firestore is to know how the DB handles reads.

Basically, every time the user opens a new tab page I will need to fetch around 3000 (very small) documents (hopefully from cache). My issue is that since opening a new tab page is done so frequently I will be charged an absurd amount of reads because firestore is always reading 3K documents.

**My question is, is Firestore smart enough to tell that in the DB data has not changed and the client should only read from the cache?**

I read all about offline persistence but this question is still lingering!

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start a listener you read first from the cache and then from the server. The cache persistance [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens) explains how it behaves but considering only that the listener is in the listening mode. Even then after a 30 in offline you would be charged for a full read.

I would recommend you to read [this](https://codeburst.io/read-and-cache-data-with-firebase-firestore-80fc5466168d). To manage your cache on your own to awoid to much reads as you are reading a large amount of data.

Comment: Thank you for linking the article! That does help save quite a lot of unnecessary reads! Have you personally successfully implemented such a caching strategy?

Comment: I personaly haven't done it. I try to read as less as possible.